# Plugin translation package issue

Tags: plugin, language, installation, packaging

I have made several translation packages to a plugin (Joomla! 3.4.1) that I have. I followed this official documentation https://docs.joomla.org/Creating_language_packs_for_extensions_in_Joomla_2.5.

When installing for the first time, every thing works as expected.
The only issue is when I need to upgrade an already installed package.
The file is replaced as expected but when I go to Extensions->Extensions Manager->Manage there will be listed both installation and should be only one.

My xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <extension type="file" version="2.5" method="upgrade">
    <name>My Plugin - French (fr-FR)</name>
    <author>author</author>
    <creationDate>Apr 2015</creationDate>
    <copyright>Copyright (C) 2014. All rights reserved.</copyright>
    <license>GNU General Public License version 3 or later; see LICENSE.txt</license>
    <authorEmail>email</authorEmail>
    <version>1.1.0</version>
    <description>fr-FR Pack de langue</description>
    <fileset>
        <files folder="fr-FR" target="administrator/language/fr-FR">
            <filename>fr-FR.plg_system_my_plugin.ini</filename>
            <filename>fr-FR.plg_system_my_plugin.sys.ini</filename>
        </files>
    </fileset>
</extension>
```

Is there a problem in my xml file?

**Found the problem.
Manifest filename wasn't the same as name field.**

Answer (score 1):

Found the problem. Manifest filename wasn't the same as name field.